# EF - Retrieve object that can be modified without effecting source data/query results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a db table containing many default attributes (for example). I would like to query the database and return one of these attributes and then be able to make changes to the returned object without modifying the source.

Basically, I would like to be able to make changes to `defaultAttribute` once retrieved without effecting the values in `_context.Attributes`.

```
DefaultAttribute defaultAttribute = new DefaultAttribute();

defaultAttribute = _context.Attributes
    .Where(u => u.Color == color && u.Size == _size)
    .Select(u => u).First();
```

Returns:

```
defaultAttribute.Color = "Black"
defaultAttribute.Size = "Small"
```

Modify object:

```
defaultAttribute.Color = "none";
defaultAttribute.Size = "none";
```

Submit query again:

```
defaultAttribute = _context.Attributes
    .Where(u => u.Color == color && u.Size == _size)
    .Select(u => u).First();
```

Returns:

```
 defaultAttribute.Color = "none"
 defaultAttribute.Size = "none"
```

But I need it to return unmodified values:

```
 defaultAttribute.Color = "Black"
 defaultAttribute.Size = "Small"
```

I don't know if I'm explaining this well enough. The above code is written off the top of my head to illustrate the problem I'm having.

How do I create a DefaultAttribute object, retrieve the values from the db and be able to make changes to DefaultAttribute without effecting the values returned from the db on subsequent calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .AsNoTracking() to detach the object from the entity context.

```
defaultAttribute = _context.Attributes
.Where(u => u.Color == color && u.Size == _size)
.Select(u => u).AsNoTracking().First();
```

In addition, you can use it before your where clause, directly on the table object itself:

```
defaultAttribute = _context.Attributes
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(u => u.Color == color && u.Size == _size)
.Select(u => u).First();
```

You will need to include the `System.Data.Entity` namespace and in Visual Basic and C#, you can call this method as an instance method on any object of type IQueryable, per [MSDN].[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679169%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try to use .AsNoTracking: `'System.Linq.IQueryable<xxxxxx.Models.xxxxParam>' does not contain a definition for 'AsNoTracking' and no extension method 'AsNoTracking' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<xxxxxx.Models.xxxxParam>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\xxx\xxxxx\Repos\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxx\Helpers\xxxxParams.cs`

Comment: Have you added using System.Linq; ? to the top of your file?

Comment: Yes. I have that using. ;)

Comment: Are you using ObjectContext instead of DbContext by chance?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. The db context is defined:         `public ProgramDbContext() : base("dbProgram") { }` with a DbSet<Object> ... I then create a ProgramDbContext and use it like _context.Object.Where( ... ) - does this help answer your question?

Comment: Please see my edits.  You SHOULD be able to call AsNoTracking directly against your dbsets, although you may need to include System.Data.Entity

Comment: Your edit worked for me on the database queries. Now I know what you meant by the object/db question. AsNoTracking() doesn't work on other than IQueriable Objects? I have some List<Object> that I would like to create editable objects from, but I don't want the edits to effect the source data. How is this done for ObjectContexts?

Comment: You could potentially reattach each object back to the ObjectContext in your list, e.g. (_context.Attributes.Attach(defaultAttribute)) but this seems a bit expensive at this point.  Perhaps restructuring your code to not be a resolved query would be better than reattaching the entity only to detach it again.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Basically, I have a table that contains rows of default settings. I want to read that table and place those values in 3 different objects. Each of the 3 objects need to be able to be edited without effecting either of the 2 other objects or the db. As it is, editing one is changing all of them. I do not need to reattach these objects.

Answer (score 0):

As David L mentioned, you can use `AsNoTracking()` to fix the issue.

Here is another way to approach it:

```
defaultAttribute = _context.Set<Attribute>().AsNoTracking()
                  .Where(u => u.Color == color && u.Size == _size)
                  .Select(u => u).First();
```

This should solve the other problem you are having: *`.. no extension method 'AsNoTracking' accepting a first argument ..`*.

You might want to include `using System.Data.Entity;`, if you have not already.